# Typical LocalBusiness Website Microdata structure

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I have a Website that typically describes an Organization/LocalBusiness/FurnitureStore and what it sells: brands (not owned), product categories, single products (not owned), service categories and single services (owned).

I need help to define the best/correct microdata structure for the whole website.

I would like to help a simple, clear example/tutorial for dummies.

**Each WebPage has the following structure:**

A. **`header`** - FurnitureStore: `logo`, `name`, `nav`.

B. **`main`**

C. **`footer`** - `FurnitureStore`: `copyrightHolder` of Website, `vatID`, `url` to "Contact us" WebPage (with `address`, `telephone`, `email` etc.), `url` to "Privacy policy" WebPage etc.

**The website has the following structure:**

**1. Homepage/`main`:**

1.1. `FurnitureStore` short `description` with `url` to "About us" WebPage.

1.2. `FurnitureStore` sold products and services categories list with `name`, `image`, `url` to single product/service `WebPage`.

1.3. `FurnitureStore` sold brands (Organizations) list with `name`, `logo`, `url` to single Organization WebPage (on this Website).

*QUESTIONS:*

a. is it better to directly use `itemtype="FurnitureStore"`, or `itemtype="LocalBusiness"` and `additionalType="FurnitureStore"`, or other solutions (`WebSite`?)?

b. In lists, is it better to put only the url to the item specific webpage, or also other details, like name, logo/image etc.

c. in products categories list is this code right?
    
    
    
    Tables

d. In (not owned) brands list, is it correct `itemprop="brand"`?

**2. "About us" WebPage/`main`:**

2.1. `FurnitureStore` long `description`.

3. "Contact us" WebPage/`main`:

3.1. Google map

3.2. Contacts and address

3.3. "Contact"/"Request quote" Form

*QUESTIONS:*

e. Both "About us" and "Contact details" WebPage are describing the `FurnitureStore`. Is it right to apply `itemscope itemtype="FurnitureStore"` to the `body`, so that `header` and `footer` microdata are applied? Is it right to apply the `itemprop="sameAs"` to the links from/to Homepage/About us/Contact us.

**4. Single “Product Category” WebPage/`main`:**

4.1. `name`

4.2. `description`

4.3. `image`s (products gallery)

*QUESTIONS:*

f. If `main` describes an `Offer`/`Category` or `Product` Is it right to apply `itemscope itemtype="FurnitureStore"` to the `body`, so that `header` and `footer` microdata are applied? Or is better to apply `itemscope itemtype="Offer"` to the `body` and `itemprop="seller"` to the `header` with `itemref="footer"`? `mainEntityOfPage` can help? Is there a better solution? What changes?

g. Obvious an `Offer`/`Category` and most Customized services have no fixed `price`: usually you must submit a request for quote. In Google snippets is it possible to show "submit a request for quote", or "starting from n EUR" or similar as `price` value?

**5. Single “Brand” WebPage/`main`:**

5.1. `name`

5.2. `description`

5.3. `image`s (products gallery)

5.4. `url` to the official website of the brand

*QUESTIONS:*

h. If `main` describes a brand, is it right to apply `itemscope itemtype="FurnitureStore"` to the `body`, so that `header` and `footer` microdata are applied? Or is better to apply `itemscope itemtype="Brand"` or `itemscope itemtype="Organization"` to the `body` and another `itemprop` (seller?) to the `header` with `itemref="footer"`? `mainEntityOfPage` can help? Is there a better solution? What changes?

Comment: This question is way too broad. Usually you should only ask one question per question post (unless they are very closely related, which is not the case for all your questions in this post). So ideally you’d create a separate question for each separate problem/question you have. -- Oh, and if you want a review of your HTML+Microdata, you could ask on [codereview.se].

Comment: There are 4 questions here, please edit and ask one question at once