# Typical LocalBusiness Product Category WebPage Microdata structure

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I have a Website that typically describes an Organization/LocalBusiness/FurnitureStore and what it sells: brands (not owned), product categories, single products (not owned), service categories and single services (owned).
I need help to define the best/correct microdata structure for the whole website.
I would like to help a simple, clear example/tutorial for dummies.

As suggested I have splitted the original question in different posts.
[Read a complete description of the problem »](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661705/typical-localbusiness-website-microdata-structure)

**Single “Product Category” WebPage**

http://www.schiano-arredamenti.it/camerette-per-bambini-e-ragazzi/

A. **`header`** - FurnitureStore: `logo`, `name`, `nav`.

B. **`main`**

1. category `name`
2. `description`
3. `image`s (gallery of products)

C. **`footer`** - `FurnitureStore`: `copyrightHolder` of Website, `vatID`, `url` to "Contact us" WebPage (with `address`, `telephone`, `email` etc.), `url` to "Privacy policy" WebPage etc.

If `main` describes an `Offer`/`Category` is it right to apply `itemscope itemtype="FurnitureStore"` to the `body`, so that `header` and `footer` microdata are applied? Or is better to apply `itemscope itemtype="Offer"` to the `body` and `itemprop="seller"` to the `header` with `itemref="footer"`? `mainEntityOfPage` can help? Is there a better solution? What changes?

Comment: Does it mean you have *two* `FurnitureStore` items (one in the header, one in the footer)? What do you mean with `Category` (in "`Offer/Category`")?

Comment: I mean that `FurnitureStore` is splitted in header and footer: is it possible to "merge" them (and set the `FurnitureStore` as `seller`)? Whit `Category` I mean a an offered product category, i.e. "Kitchens", not a single kitchen product, as an "Arredo3 Wega" kitchen specific configuration.

Comment: You can have a look to a test code at http://www.schiano-arredamenti.it/camerette-per-bambini-e-ragazzi/

Comment: I did, but it only contains a `LocalBusiness` and an `Offer`, right? Anyway, I tried to answer what I think is your core question here. Feel free to comment if anything’s unclear or if I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0):

When using Microdata, you don’t "annotate" the HTML5 elements. The HTML5 elements just serve as a carrier, so to say.

So from the Microdata perspective, it does not matter which of these you’d choose:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Foo</h1>
</div>
```

```html
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
  <span itemprop="name">Foo</span>
</span>
```

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="Foo" />
</div>
```

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemref="bar">
</div>
<div itemprop="name" id="bar">Foo</div>
```

It’s all the same to Microdata, it only cares about the parsed name-value pairs. (But keep in mind that some elements are for [different types of values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871012/1591669), so if you have a date, you’d have to use `time`, and if you have a URL, you’d have to use `a`, `link` etc.).

Also note that Microdata does not care about an `itemscope`-element’s content, it only looks for `itemprop` values. So in this example, `<p>Foobar</p>` is *not* part of the Microdata:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
  <p>Foobar</p>
</div>
```

So choose HTML5 elements according to their definitions (i.e., [semantic markup](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/semantic-markup)) and then, in a second step, apply Microdata as needed. If your HTML structure doesn’t allow something you want to convey (and you can’t change it), you may add `meta` and `link` elements as needed.

**tl;dr:** It does not matter which `itemtype` you use on the `body` and which on the `main` element, as long as you can state what you want to state. It mostly depends on your HTML structure, and what is easier for you to implement.